# How to optimize one big insert with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, bulkinsert

For my website, I'm creating a book database. I have a catalog, with a root node, each node have subnodes, each subnode has documents, each document has versions, and each version is made of several paragraphs.
In order to create this database the fastest possible, I'm first creating the entire tree model, in memory, and then I call session.save(rootNode)
This single save will populate my entire database (at the end when I'm doing a mysqldump on the database it weights 1Go)
The save coasts a lot (more than an hour), and since the database grows with new books and new versions of existing books, it coasts more and more. I would like to optimize this save.

I've tried to increase the batch_size. But it changes nothing since it's a unique save. When I mysqldump a script, and I insert it back into mysql, the operation coast 2 minutes or less.
And when I'm doing a "htop" on the ubuntu machine, I can see the mysql is only using 2 or 3 % CPU. Which means that it's hibernate who's slow.

If someone could give me possible techniques that I could try, or possible leads, it would be great... I already know some of the reasons, why it takes time. If someone wants to discuss it with me, thanks for his help.

Here are some of my problems (I think): For exemple, I have self assigned ids for most of my entities. Because of that, hibernate is checking each time if the line exists before it saves it. I don't need this because, the batch I'm executing, is executed only one, when I create the databse from scratch. The best would be to tell hibernate to ignore the primaryKey rules (like mysqldump does) and reenabeling the key checking once the database has been created. It's just a one shot batch, to initialize my database.

Second problem would be again about the foreign keys. Hibernate inserts lines with null values, then, makes an update in order to make foreign keys work.

About using another technology : I would like to make this batch work with hibernate because after, all my website is working very well with hibernate, and if it's hibernate who creates the databse, I'm sure the naming rules, and every foreign keys will be well created.

Finally, it's a readonly database. (I have a user database, which is using innodb, where I do updates, and insert while my website is running, but the document database is readonly and mYisam)

Here is a exemple of what I'm doing

```
TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode();
recursiveLoadSubNodes(rootNode); // This method creates my big tree, in memory only.

hibernateSession.beginTrasaction();
hibernateSession.save(rootNode); // during more than an hour, it saves 1Go of datas : hundreads of sub treeNodes, thousands of documents, tens of thousands paragraphs.
hibernateSession.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: "I already know some of the reasons, why it takes time" - note that it might help to include those and your reasoning about those into your question. That shows effort on your part and makes it easier to understand your situation (problem, knowledge etc.) and thus makes it easier to provide suggestions.

Comment: Sorry for that. I just wanted to know first if I'm on the right forum before explaining all. I've added some details to my first post.

Comment: Please Thomas, can I ask you something? What is the best way to complete my question (like you said I could have given the details right from the start)? Should I answer to my own post, or should I complete and edit the first post? If I edit the question, the answer may seem off topic. (Sorry it's the first time I ask for help)

Comment: "I've added some details to my first post." - note that it would be better to add details to your question via an [edit]. Otherwise it could get confusing. As for the details themselves: it depends (ouch, very helpful ;) ). Including some relevant parts of the model (and the mapping), your saving process, details on what you've observed, e.g. log entries - if they are too long then you should try to remove unnecessary parts like irrelevant columns etc. - In general code is more precise than trying to explain it yourself. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hard to guess what could be the problem here but I could think of 3 things:

- Increasing batch_size only might not help because - depending on your model - inserts might be interleaved (i.e. `A B A B ...`). You can allow Hibernate to reorder inserts and updates so that they can be batched (i.e. `A A ... B B ...`).
  Depending on your model this might not work because the inserts might not be batchable. The necessary properties would be `hibernate.order_inserts` and `hibernate.order_updates` and a blog post that describes the situation can be found here: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/
- If the entities don't already exist (which seems to be the case) then the problem might be the first level cache. This cache will cause Hibernate to get slower and slower because each time it wants to flush changes it will check *all* entries in the cache by iterating over them and calling `equals()` (or something similar). As you can see that will take longer with each new entity that's created.
  To Fix that you could either try to disable the first level cache (I'd have to look up whether that's possible for write operations and how this is done - or you do that :) ) or try to keep the cache small, e.g. by inserting the books yourself and evicting each book from the first level cache after the insert (you could also go deeper and do that on the document or paragraph level).
- It might not actually be Hibernate (or at least not alone) but your DB as well. Note that restoring dumps often removes/disables constraint checks and indices along with other optimizations so comparing that with Hibernate isn't that useful. What you'd need to do is create a bunch of insert statements and then just execute those - ideally via a JDBC batch - on an empty database but with all constraints and indices enabled. That would provide a more accurate benchmark.

  Assuming that comparison shows that the plain SQL insert isn't that much faster then you could decide to either keep what you have so far or refactor your batch insert to temporarily disable (or remove and re-create) constraints and indices.

Alternatively you could try not to use Hibernate at all or change your model - if that's possible given your requirements which I don't know. That means you could try to generate and execute the SQL queries yourself, use a NoSQL database or NoSQL storage in a SQL database that supports it - like Postgres.

We're doing something similar, i.e. we have Hibernate entities that contain some complex data which is stored in a JSONB column. Hibernate can read and write that column via a custom usertype but it can't filter (Postgres would support that but we didn't manage to enable the necessary syntax in Hibernate).

Comment: Thanks for those leads. I'll read the link you gave me. I've added some informations to my first post about what kind of problems I think I've identified... Thanks :-D